# What's the meaning of 'wonder'ff'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

A guy just came out of a party and within two minutes went into a ditch with his car, and made it wrecked. But he seemed not to realize the situation quite well yet, drunken, and said like this, what’s the meaning?

> “Wonder‘ff tell me where there’s gas’line station?” (F. Scott
>   Fitzgerald, The Great Gatsby)

Comment: This is another case of Eye Dialect. Hence, I think this is a duplicate of this: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5281/why-is-this-possessive-not-objective-case

Comment: I think it's Too Localised, same as the other one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a contraction of *wonder if* with slurring of the *if* (due to drunkenness).  Similarly, *gas'line* is *gasoline*.

Comment: "due to drunkenness" is localized to the context of this quotation. There are other reasons for slurring, for example a speech impediment. Or maybe even just talking fast.