# Don't we need an article when we call a pet?

Tags: indefinite-article

> *I’ll get you animal.* ([reference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5281/why-is-this-possessive-not-objective-case))

If we mention a pet, do we not use an article (for it is a family), or have to use one nonetheless?

Comment: I think this should be closed as a duplicate of this question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5281/why-is-this-possessive-not-objective-case

Comment: This is also the third question in as many days about the ungrammaticality of Hagrid's quoted speech. To save time later, here's a rule of thumb that you may find helpful: *Most of Hagrid's quoted speech is a combination of Eye Dialect and verbatim transcription. It is not (and it is not intended to be) grammatical English*.

Comment: ... and about Eye Dialect see for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_Dialect

Comment: @Matt I would (cautiously) extend that to most quoted dialog in novels/written stories, *especially* in cases  where there are lots of unusual contractions and/or slang. This is usually an indication that the author is intending to imitate a spoken dialect with his/her writing, and as such *should not* be taken as an example of grammatical English.

Comment: Maybe the comma is missing: "I'll get you, animal."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reference you cite shows that the speaker (Hagrid, probably) uses "**yer**" to mean both **your** ("I'll get (1) **yer** animal" and "carry (3) **yer** mail") and **you** ("I'll get (2) **yer** an owl.").

In general, however, you're correct. The sentence in standard English requires the article "**an**": *I'll get you **an** animal*.